# How can I bulid an custom acyclic model?

Tags: graph, deep-learning, keras

I 'm beginning Keras and I'm trying to build a custom acyclic model. I need output returned for hidden layer. I'm sending illustration image. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0eJkvcHNZP4cDVZZ3M0U1pYaHM/view)

The model remember a RNN, but doesn't infinity states, therefore the build it must be simple model
Can someone help me?

Comment: how is that model acyclic?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut, above I posted the [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0eJkvcHNZP4cDVZZ3M0U1pYaHM/view)

Comment: @TiagoAlves This model is not acyclic, it has a cycle.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Can I help me? I am not to get implement this model. At moment, I'm using Keras alone.

Comment: @TiagoAlves Not until you clarify the questions in the comments, you have ignored them.

Comment: I thought it was a cyclic model, but in the Keras forum on github they said it was an acyclic model for not having endless state transitions like the LSTM. Although, in fact, it is a recurring model so I was a bit confused about the denomination.

Remember: I have a CNN, between the layers, I have a dense layer that receives the context information of the model exit, thus creating a recurrence as it is in the figure.

Before I was using the keras sequential template, I'm currently trying to do with the keras Graph model, but I'm not getting it.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro do you speak Portuguese? This would be easier for me. :)